# JQuery: Don't want "Open Hover" state on accordion menu

Tags: jquery, css, hover, accordion

### Hi Everyone

I have an accordion menu that I've adapted from [this](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ddaccordion.htm) one I found on DynamicDrive.com.
Instead of the typical UL type accordion, this one hides and reveals DIVs.

I need 3 states for the headings:

- **Closed** (black text / white background)
- **Closed Hover** (white text / black background)
- **Open** (red text / white background)

At the moment there is a 4th state (**Open Hover**), but I don't want this.

**How do I make the open state have *no* hover?** (or have it's on unique hover state). At the moment the script applies the same *closed-hover* css style to the *open-hover* state.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gaelen/mgpXK/1/) is the code on JSFiddle. I know there is a lot of JavaScript there, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean like this: [**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/cX8uu/)

if that's what you're after the only changes are in the CSS.. I had to make the `.openheader` link rule more specific (by putting the a in front of it) to match the specificity of the `a.menuitem` links.. then made sure all the `a.menuitem` rules were preceding the `a.openheader` one

Comment: Brilliant, thanks clairesuzy, That's exactly what I was after!